# Why we dont use dot operator with int or any other datatype

Tags: object-oriented

Okay so imma noob as my question itself will suggest . And I know that of If I want to access a public class member we have to use the dot operator with the object .
So we know that int , float etc are also classes ..so why don't we use dot operators with the variables of that data type...?

Comment: This seems language-specific but, in general, the dot operator is usually used to access member variables or functions. What are you expecting to access? Also note that in some languages the usual infix notation with arithmetic operator is just a shorthand for a function call. For example `a*b` could be just a syntactic sugar for `a.product_operator(b)`. In other languages (e.g. Java) ints (and other primitive types) are not objects, and there are classes (e.g. `java.lang.Integer`) that wrap these types into objects.

Comment: Programing questions are off topic here. Stackoverflow is better suited for such questions.

Comment: "we know that int , float etc are also classes": I don't know that.

Comment: BTW, I don't think dot notation is an operator. Per my understanding, an operator performs some, well, operation on operands, and the operands must be a well-defined expression. When you write `a.b`, 1) `b` is not defined by itself, i.e. it's inseparable from `a.b`, and 2) `b` must be a literal, i.e. any other expression is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

There are languages where "everything is an object". The archetype is Smalltalk, although Smalltalk does not think in terms of "method calls", but rather "messages".

In Smalltalk (and its offshoots like Squeak), mathematical operations on numeric classes are binary messages. This has interesting implications when it interacts with Smalltalk's syntax. This:

```
3 + 2 * 5
```

returns `25`, not `13`, because you send the "plus 2" message to 3, and then the "times 5" message to that. There's no reason why there can't be better syntactic sugar, of course.

This approach also has nontrivial interactions with the type system of the language, especially if the language is more strongly typed, because real algebras are often many-sorted. Consider, for example, how you would represent `time` and `duration` types. Conceptually, a `duration` is the difference between two `time`s. It makes sense to add one hour to three hours (`duration + duration`), and it makes sense to add one hour to 3pm (`duration + time`), but it doesn't make sense to add 3pm to 4pm (`time + time`).

Expressing this as methods in a way that also allows generic functions which take any two types that can be "added together" is not easy when you have a Simula-like object model.

In most programming languages where most things are objects, basic types typically are not objects. As Steven pointed out in a comment, this isn't true of Java, but Java provides classes which wrap them if you need to treat them as objects. It's a similar (though not identical) story with C#.

Another increasingly common approach is to use what Haskell calls "type classes" and Rust calls "traits". In these languages, a class is not a type, but a collection of types which have common operations. Both [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html) and [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/index.html) have ways to declare that a type is a member of a numeric operation class without making those operations "methods" of the type.